# Wordpress - Page Redirects based on user's IP

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have come up with the following solution:

CREATE TABLE `logger` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `landing` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

See if entry exists
select id, landing from logger where ip = INET_ATON('10.0.5.9') and updated >  date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,interval -2 DAY) order by id desc limit 1;

If exists update. This shall automatically update the updated field
update logger set landing = 'landing' where id = 1;

If not exist add the entry
insert into logger (ip, landing) value (INET_ATON('10.0.5.9'), '/');

Could anyone help me with the php bits to add into my headers as i have successfully sorted the MySQL bits now.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: The answer is probably sessions / cookies. This is simple, with built in php functions. But what happends if they visit the url on the business card, then see the TV advert and follow that url? What homepage do they see?

Comment: Its very easy to collect the IP and drop a cookie but if you already know where the user is coming from then why not pass the soucce in the url as a parameter and then drop a cookie based on the source? IP's are no more reliable

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? [Cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) are easy to set up, and you can set them on the first visit, and read them on the second visit etc. (Using an `if` statement or something similar). Using the global variable `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` you can get a user's IP. I wouldn't suggest using IP's for this, since they can easily be changed or shared. Maybe read how the user got on the page, then set a cookie based on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution would be to use a special URL that you would link to from email campaigns, where the "real" adress is added as query parameter:

Example which would redirect to http://example.com/foo
http://example.com/campaign.php?forward_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo&campaign=bar

In that script you set a cookie and forward to the actual address

```
<?php 
   setcookie('campaign', $_GET['campaign']);
   header('Location: ' + $_GET['forward_to']);  
?>
```

Note that this script needs to be on the same domain. You could also do this without a redirect by just setting up a hook in functions.php and looking for a `campaign` query sting parameter and serving different stylesheets based on that. Example:

(this assumes that you have campaign specific stylesheets located in `mytheme/styles/` named `campaign-1.css, campaign-2.css` )

```
// in /functions.php

/**
* Sets cookie if 'campaign' var is passed in url
*/
function get_campaign_code($query_vars) {
    if (isset($query_vars['campaign'])) {
        setcookie('campaign_code', $query_vars['campaign']);
    }
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'get_campaign_code');

/**
* Enqueue a campaign specific stylesheet if $_COOKIE['campaign_code'] is available
*/
function enqueue_campaign_stylesheet() {

    $cid = $_COOKIE['campaign_code'];

    if ( $_COOKIE['campaign_code'] ) {
         // creates uri to campaign specific  
         $src = sprintf('%s/styles/campaign-%d.css', 
                    get_template_directory_uri(),
                    $cid
                    );
         wp_enqueue_style( 'campaign_css', $src);
    }  
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'function_name');
```

Comment: This sounds like the way to go. Would you be able to exlpain it in dummy terms though - sorry. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Be carefull with this. "example.com/campaign.php?forward_to=http%3A%2F%2FMY-EVIL-SITE.com" An attacker may craft an url to make a phishing attack. Check this url to get more info https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @jspurim very good point. I was just trying to demonstrate the general concept. In production you should use a whitelist of acceptable values.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the ip to identify an user, use sessions instead (that is, use the cookie)

```
<?php
session_start();

//Set the correct page if not set already
if(!isset($_SESSION['page']){
  if(userCameFromEmail)
    $_SESSION['page'] = "someUrl1";
  else if(userCameFromTV)
    $_SESSION['page'] = "someUrl2";
  else if(userCameFromCard)
    $_SESSION['page'] = "someUrl3";
}

//Redirect
header("Location: " . $_SESSION['page']);

?>
```

This way the user will see the same page he saw the first time as long as he keeps the cookie. Keep  present that this doesn't forbid access to the other urls. If you wan't to restrict access that's more difficult. You could add a different random code in each of your business cards, and ask for it in the page. Same goes for the email. The TV page is by definition public I guess you don't want to restrict access to it.

Comment: Would this just go in the header.php fie of my theme, with the correct page and urls included in the code?

Comment: The answer is kind of pseudo-code. I don't know how you identify the page the first time. If you use separate urls, the triple if could be split among three files (keep the if(!isset($_SESSION['page') in all them!)
The redirection should be on your header, but keep in mind if the page is not set, you should define a default.

Comment: So i would add some php session info in each of the three home page templates which would add redirects. Could you give me an example of this please. Sorry to be a pain, i just can't work out where in your code to replace my page names and urls.